# Using solr cloud server how can we add a document

Tags: apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

While adding a document using solr cloud server I am getting zookeeper connection exception.
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're connected to ZooKeeper?
If you run Solr with embedded ZK the ZK port is Solr port - 1000, for example 8983-1000 => 7973

If you are sure that you use the correct connection details, then you can always increase the ZK connection time out in you CloudSolrServer object  setZkConnectTimeout(int) - if you are using Solrj client.

This will probably fix the problem but you should investigate why you are getting ZK timeout.
In the new Solr versions the default timeout increased to 3000ms from 1800ms, so if you are using old version of Solr change it.